# Check if reference is present at compile time

Tags: c#, compiler-construction, reference

Is is possible to check if a reference is present in a project at compile time in C#?

For example;

```
public void myMethod()
{
    #if REVIT_DLL_2014
       TopographySurface.Create(vertices); // This function only exists in Revit2014.dll
       // So I will get a compiler if another DLL is used 
       // ie, Revit2013.dll, because this method (Create) wont exist
    #else // using Revit2013.dll
       // use alternate method to create a surface
    #endif
}
```

What I want to avoid is having 2 separate C# projects to maintain (ie, a Version 2013 and a Version 2014) because they are the same in almost every way except for 1 feature.

I guess my last resort might be (but it would be nicer if the above feature was possible):

```
#define USING_REVIT_2014

public void myMethod()
{
    #if USING_REVIT_2014
       TopographySurface.Create(vertices); // This function only exists in Revit2014.dll
       // So I will get a compiler if another DLL is used because this method (Create) wont exist
    #else // using Revit2013.dll
       // use alternate method to create a surface
    #endif
}
```

Comment: I didn't know that you could use #DEFINE and #IF, e.t.c in C#: I thought it was only C or C++

Comment: @Joe yeah you can use `define` and `if` BUT you cant do this (which is really annoying) `#if x > y` only simple if statements like `#if DEBUG`

Comment: 'Create' is a static method?

Comment: @AlessandroD'Andria yes its static

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do your detection at runtime instead of compile time.

```
if (Type.GetType("Full.Name.Space.To.TopographySurface") != null) {
    TopographySurface.Create(vertices);
}
else {
    // use alternate method to create a surface
}
```

This assumes that as long as `TopographySurface` is defined then `Create` exists.

Comment: @JakeM - then you can use reflection to check if a type exists.  See updated answer.

Comment: I would be tempted to put this in an encapsulating class, so that you do not litter your codebase with type checking.  In addition, I would name the encapsulating class the same: `TopographySurface`, just in your own namespace.  That way when you decide to drop support for 2013 its a simple matter of changing your `using` statements.

Answer (score 0):

I depends on if you are using late biding or early biding.
Late binding:
-no compiling time warnings/errors
-only runtime errors

Early biding:
-compiler errors
-runtime errors

Comment: And? how does it answer the question?

Comment: @lauCosma thanks for the reply but either solution would still involve a runtime error. I guess I could check at runtime if the reference is present? But its better to do at compile time if possible.

Comment: checkout the following post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1111264/can-i-catch-a-missing-dll-error-during-application-load-in-c

Comment: you can try catch the reference... but that would still be at runtime... so i think that the best solution so far is a runtime error.